# Refresh list after deleting record in grocery crud

Tags: codeigniter, record

I am using grocery crud in codeigniter. When I click the delete icon in the list the record get deleted but the page will not get refresh so please tell me how to refresh the list after deleting the record.

Answer (score -1):

you can use a callback and use redirect http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/callback_after_delete

```
public function listar(){

    ...
    $crud->callback_after_delete(array($this,'user_after_delete'));
    $output = $crud->render();
$this->load->view('clientes_desactivar', $output);
    ...
}
public function user_after_delete($primary_key)
{
    redirect('clientes_desactivar/listar'.'?base='.$_GET["base"],'refresh');
}
```